# My GAM smoothing function in R is producing a straight line instead of curve

Tags: r, smoothing, gam

I need some help please. I am trying to smoothing an NDVI dataset I have so that I can extract daily values of NDVI. I performed the smoothing on a previous dataset and got a good fit ([image: See image]). Now, I tried to perform the same smoothing on a new dataset but I am getting a smooth line instead of a curve. Below are my codes:

```
library(janitor)

ndvifile2 <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/1q13uym7h2medtq/adj_Final_NDVI_Mar10.txt?dl=1" , sep = "\t", header = T) %>% clean_names()

yf2 <- ndvifile2$ndvi_p50
xf2 <- ndvifile2$julian

# Visualize dataset by plotting
plot(xf2, yf2, type = "l")

# Change class from character to numeric
y.new2 <- as.numeric(yf2)

# Number of days from 'each date' in the dataset to the 'first date' in the dataset
days.since2 <- as.numeric(xf2- min(xf2))

# Visualize new variabes (numeric ndvi and number of days)
plot(days.since2,y.new2,typ="l")

#Smoothing by Gaussian model
library(mgcv)
m2 <- gam(y.new2 ~ s(days.since2,k=40))
plot(days.since2,y.new2,typ="l")

#Predict values over a given time interval
E.y2 <- predict(m2,newdata=data.frame(days.since2=0:10957))
points(0:10957,E.y2,col="gold",typ="l")
```

This is the result I am getting from the code above:
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to smooth that data reliably without providing more information about the time effect.

Your first model worked because it has a lot of data for (what I presume is) the seasonal cycle in the time series. As such, with 40 or more basis functions it could model the multi-seasonal series as a very wiggly smooth.

Your second data set has many fewer values and some seasonal cycles seem to be defined by single data points.

A better approach for the first data set would have been to decompose the series into seasonal and between-year terms:

```
gam(y ~ s(doy, bs = "cc") + s(year), data = foo, method = "RMEL",
    knots = list(doy = c(0.5, 366.5))
```

for example, which you can then modify to allow for the seasonal cycle top vary over the years smoothly say

```
gam(y ~ s(doy, bs = "cc") + s(year) + ti(doy, year, bs = c("cc","tp")),
    data = foo, method = "RMEL", knots = list(doy = c(0.5, 366.5))
```

If you have enough days within the year to estimate a seasonal smooth (you might have to set `k` lower than the default `10` if you don't have that many unique day-of-year (`doy`) values) then you might be able to get the first model to work.

It's heard to say more; I don't really understand the data or why you are modelling this as `days.since2` instead of via `doy` (a day of year variable) and `year` for the long term trend.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. Although, I don't fully understand the steps since I'm an amateur in R. The data is NDVI data from Landsat for 30 years. the data is available every 16 days, so I am trying to apply a smoothing curve to the available data and then using the `doy`, I can extract an estimate of the NDVI value at daily time steps rather than just having data for every 16 days.